# Login page is Flickering in OpenERP

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

When ever i try to open Login page of OpenERP , I will first find Sign up, Reset Password , Back to Login options, and later normal Login Page will come.U can clearly find in attached images image 1 ,image 2 . Can anyone tell me how to solve this flickering issue.Thank's in advance.
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Hi nitesh, I think this is the openerp registration for new user login pane that loads initially and after checking the condtion they reload the page. I'm not sure as to where this can be overriden to avoid this from happening.